# CS50 - Week4 Memory Practice Problem Correct (Licenses), but Memory Leakage Issue

Tags: c, cs50

The memory leakage occurs in the while loop where I am allocating space using malloc for a char* temp.

I know that everytime I set temp to NULL and I free it, plates[idx] is set to the heap memory that initially belonged to temp. But I do not know how to fix this issue.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    // Check for command line args
    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./read infile\n");
        return 1;
    }

    // Create buffer to read into
    char buffer[7];



    // Create array to store plate numbers
    char *plates[8];

    FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

    if(infile == NULL)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    int idx = 0;

    while (fread(buffer, 1, 7 , infile) == 7)
    {

        char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);

        // Replace '\n' with '\0'
        buffer[6] = '\0';

        if(temp != NULL)
        {
            strcpy(temp, buffer);
        }

        plates[idx] = temp;
        temp = NULL;

        free(temp);
        idx++;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
    }


    fclose(infile);
}
```

I had no idea what to do. I though of maybe setting another variable located in the stack equal to the address of memory in heap, then go from there.

Comment: These statements         temp = NULL;

        free(temp); do not free the allocated memory. because the function free is called for a null pointer.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what is the purpose of `free`? What do you think should happen, if you call `free` with a pointer that is null? What do you think should happen, if you call `free` with a pointer that isn't null? (If you don't know, [did you try](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) to find out - for example, by using a search engine, reading a textbook or course notes, etc.?) If you write `temp  = NULL;` and then `free(temp);` which of those two things will happen first? Therefore, will `free` be called with a null pointer? Do you see the problem?

Comment: In your own words, where the code says `char *temp = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);`, what is the purpose of that line? What is the purpose *of the allocated memory*? Therefore, *when* should it be deallocated*? (Hint: you then store a pointer to that memory into the `plates` array, correct? The purpose of that array is to keep track of those pointers to the allocations, right? What does the code do with those pointers later? When will it be done with the pointers?)

Answer (score 3):

```c
        temp = NULL;

        free(temp);
```

is telling `free()` to free nothing. (this operation is safe, just do nothing)

The pointer `temp` is stored to `plates[idx]` and later referenced, so it mustn't be freed in the loop.

You should delete the confusing `free(temp);` line and add `free(plates[i]);` after the `printf("%s\n", plates[i]);` line.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for this solution. I tried to avoid using a temp file (just to experiment) and turns out we don't need a temp file if we just assign memory to plates[idx]. Here is my code -

```
char *plates[8];

FILE *infile = fopen(argv[1], "r");

int idx = 0;

while (fread(buffer, 1, 7, infile) == 7)
{
    plates[idx] = malloc(sizeof(char) * 7);
    
    // Replace '\n' with '\0'
    buffer[6] = '\0';

    // Save plate number in array
    if (plates[idx] != NULL)
    {
        strcpy(plates[idx], buffer);
    }
    idx++;
}

for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
{
    printf("%s\n", plates[i]);
    free(plates[i]);
}

fclose(infile);
```

}